# SQLITE JOIN twice ON same table and same column

Tags: sqlite, join

Fixtures

```
+-----------+-----------+ 
| home_team | away_team |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 2         |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Teams

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 1    | AC Milan  |
+------+-----------+
| 2    | AS Roma   |
+------+-----------+
```

I have these two tables, and I want to query it in order to have :

```
(1, 2, AC Milan, AS Roma)
```

I tried this :

```
SELECT fixtures.home_teams, fixtures.away_team, teams.name FROM fixtures JOIN teams ON fixtures.home_team = teams.id JOIN teams ON fixtures.away_team = teams.id
```

but I keep getting an error :

```
Result: ambiguous column name: teams.name
```

Comment: You need to alias the table name on all the joins except the first one. Otherwise, it's impossible to tell which `teams.name` you're referencing, because there is more than one of them in your SQL.  (I personally alias the first one as well, because it makes it easier for me to follow the logic when I come back to the code a year from now.)

Answer (score 0):

Each of the 2 copies of the table `teams` must have its own alias which will be used to qualify the names of the columns:

```
SELECT f.home_team, t1.name home_team_name, 
       f.away_team, t2.name away_team_name 
FROM fixtures f
JOIN teams t1 ON f.home_team = t1.id 
JOIN teams t2 ON f.away_team = t2.id;
```